# IntelliSense:expected a declaration in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am trying add C and C++ code together, but end up with getting above error as `IntelliSense:expected a declaration`.

e.g
`abc.cpp`

```
#include "abc.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
#include "C_headerfiles.h"
...
...//Body of C code
#ifdef _cplusplus
}
#endif
...
...//Body of C plus plus code

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"       //`IntelliSense:expected a declaration
{
#endif
...
...//Body of C code
#ifdef _cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: I like how the same error occurs twice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1041880/1488917 Maybe this could help.

Comment: You are aware that Intellisense errors are just hints? Did you try to just build?

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz: Yes, I did try build.

Comment: So what was the actual build error?

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz: I found the solution. I wrote my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem: Need to add the `extern C` `only once` not `again and again`.

```
#include "abc.h"
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
#include "C_headerfiles.h"
...
...//Body of C code

...
...//Body of C plus plus code


...
...//Body of C code
#ifdef _cplusplus
}
#endif
```